# Could not cast value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' (0x11beb7040) to 'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible' (0x11beb9040)

Tags: swift3, alamofire

when build my code then crash on  `Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON()`. pls suggest how to fix this crash

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON(){ response in

       switch response.result
       {
          case .success(let data):                
             print(" i got my Data Yup",data)          
          case .failure(let error):
             print(error)                                
        }
    }
```

Comment: May be this create Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON() problem.

Comment: Also in 2nd line you are using let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url! as URL) But in 5th line you take request as! **URLRequestConvertible** . Why? I think no need of it. Try it without convertible.

Answer (score 16):

In Swift 3, all you have to do is to change NSMutableURLRequest to URLRequest and it will work. No need to cast.
Also, set var so it can be swift mutable. :) Thanks, Markus for comment.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Also don't forget to set var instead of let to make it mutable.

Answer (score 10):

change `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url! as URL)` to
    `var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)`
your code look like this:-

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON(){ response in

           switch response.result
           {
              case .success(let data):                
                 print(" i got my Data Yup",data)          
              case .failure(let error):
                 print(error)                                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would you like to augment your code-only answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with following syntax for request method:

```
Alamofire.request(strURL,method: .post, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```