# How to convert URLRequest to Alamofire.URLConvertible

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rxalamofire

how to covert URLRequest to Alamofire URLConvertible I am getting error while trying to convert following is my code

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "some url")!)
request.httpBody = json
RxAlamofire.request(.post, request as! URLConvertible, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Content-Type" : "application/json"])
    .subscribe(onNext:{ [weak self] (json) in
        print(json)
        if let jsonResult = JSON(json) as? JSON {
            if let cartResult = FoodCartResult(jsonResult) as? FoodCartResult {
                self?.delegate?.showCart(cartresult: cartResult)
            }
        }

        }, onError: {
            [weak self] (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self?.delegate?.onError()
        },onCompleted: {})
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

code is crashing my app saying

> Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.URLRequest' (0x10c23a3c8) to 'Alamofire.URLConvertible'

Already referred following but not working for me
[Could not cast value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' (0x11beb7040) to 'Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible' (0x11beb9040)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114689/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsmutableurlrequest-0x11beb7040-to-alamofire-u)

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114689/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsmutableurlrequest-0x11beb7040-to-alamofire-u

Comment: please check code I am doing the same still getting exception