# URLRequest to Alamofire URLConvertible

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have found the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114689/could-not-cast-value-of-type-nsmutableurlrequest-0x11beb7040-to-alamofire-u) but not worked for me. thats why I'm posting this again.
The following code gives me an error.

Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.URLRequest' to 'Alamofire.URLConvertible'

the code sample:

```
    let url = (wURL).replacingOccurrences(of: "(f_id)", with: String(conID))
    let _url = URL(string: url)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: _url!)
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = TimeInterval(exactly: 30)!
    
    let finalUrl = urlRequest as! URLConvertible
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need to cast your `URLRequest` into `URLConvertible`. Just pass it to Alamofire as an `URLRequest` and it will work.

Comment: Hello, have you been able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it, because for `URLRequest` there is special protocol `URLRequestConvertible`.

```
let realURL: URL = URL(string: "https://google.com")!

let url: Alamofire.URLConvertible = realURL

let urlRequest: Alamofire.URLRequestConvertible = URLRequest(url: realURL)

AF.request(urlRequest).responseJSON {
    print($0)
}
```